# How do I write the equals() method in this context?

Tags: java

I need to write a Temperature.equals() method that compares the first temperature to the second temperature in the parenthesis, but I don't know the proper syntax to.

Part 1:

```
public Temperature(double degreesd, char typec)
{
   degrees = degreesd;
   type = typec;
}

public void set(double degreesd, char typec)
{
   degrees = degreesd;
   type = typec;
}
```

Part 2:

```
t1.set(100, 'C');
t2.set(212, 'F');
System.out.println(t1.equals(t2));
```

The equals() method I need to finish:

```
public boolean equals(Temperature t2)
{
   return ( Temperature.getC() == t2.getC() );
   // getC() is a function that returns degrees in Celsius as a double.
}
```

I don't know the proper syntax to pass t1 into where "Temperature.getC()" is. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public boolean equals(Temperature t2)
{
   return (this.getC() == t2.getC());
   // getC() is a function that returns degrees in Celsius as a double.
}
```

Use `this` to reference the object on which you call `equals`. In the case of `t1.equals(t2)`, `this` will be `t1`.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier using the `getC()` method, then you don't have to get into trouble like me:

```
public boolean equals(Temperature t1) {
    return this.getC() == t1.getC();
}
```

---

As for the `euqals` method (without using `getC()`):

```
public boolean equals(Temperature t1) {
    if (this.typec == t1.typec) {
        return (this.degrees == t1.degrees);
    } else {
        double fah = t1.typec == 'F' ? t1.degrees : t2.degrees;
        double cel = t1.typec == 'C' ? t1.degrees : t2.degrees;
        fah = (fah - 32) * 5 / 9;
        return fah == cel;
    }
}
```

Comment: But I have fixed it now (so, perhaps the downvote can be removed?)

Comment: A getter might be useful, but it's not necessary at all to implement equals()

Comment: Did OP ever mention he needed to implement a getter?

Comment: @JBNizet Oh, forgot about it... fixed now.

Comment: And, what about the type? 50°C != 50°F

Comment: @JBNizet Completely overlooked that part... fixing it.

Comment: As per what OP says: // getC() is a function that returns degrees in Celsius as a double; thus, it should be safe to assume a postcondition of the getter is that 50 F would be converted into C.

Comment: @AlexM. I had lost my head back there... take a look (please).